# Fastest way to detect which character is different than a specific encoding

Tags: java, encoding

At the moment I have an exception that tells me when the full line contains an invalid ISO 8859-1 character but I would like to detect exactly which one is it.

I could check each and every character in the string but that would be quite inefficient.

The purpose of this is to report to the user of the tool that they wrote an invalid character like €

Input:

```
Hello fri€nd
```

Output:

```
Error in € (index 9)
```

Is there any fast and efficient way to achieve that?

Snippet of the actual method:

```
public void writeLine(String line) throws EncodingException {
    try {
        if (!Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1" ).newEncoder().canEncode(line)) throw new EncodingException();
        bufferedWriter.write(line);
        bufferedWriter.newLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
```

Comment: You could split the line in 2 equal parts and check which part contains the error. Then recursively do the same thing on the part with the error.

Comment: That would be divide and conquer, not a bad option indeed! @RobertKock

Comment: There's no need to add "Thanks" at the end of posts. See [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) for more info

Comment: Sorry about that @Zoe I will check it for sure!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i could check each and every char in the string but that would be
>   quite inneficient

What do you think `canEncode` is doing? There's no way to check all of the characters without *checking all of the characters*.

If your String is *really long* you may see some benefit from using parallel streams:

```
final OptionalInt firstInvalidChar = line.chars()
    .parallel()
    .filter(ch -> !Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1").newEncoder().canEncode((char) ch))
    .findFirst();

if (firstInvalidChar.isPresent()) {
    throw new EncodingException(
        "The first invalid char is: " + (char) firstInvalidChar.getAsInt()
    );
}
```

If the `Charset` were thread-safe you could see some performance improvement by creating a single instance rather than lots, but as its an abstract factory with nothing in the documentation, we have to assume that it's not.

Comment: Seems like a really fast way of doing it and does exactly what I was asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [Apache Tika](https://tika.apache.org/) to detect the encoding of a String.

Example:

```
CharsetDetector detector = new CharsetDetector();
detector.setText(string.getBytes());
detector.detect();
```

Then you can convert your string from the original charset to anyone:

```
detector.getString(yourStr.getBytes(), "utf-8");
```

Comment: it is more a detection and reporting of error. Something like:

Input: Hello€ Output: Error in € value

Answer (score 0):

You basically have two options for tracking down the encoding error in your snippet:

- Check each character individually with `canEncode(char c)`
- Try to configure your encoder to throw an [UnmappableCharacterException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/UnmappableCharacterException.html), which contains an `inputLength` which will tell you the position of the faulty character. This is triggered by setting the [CodingErrorAction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CodingErrorAction.html) on the CharsetEncoder, but I'm not confident that this works across all encodings.

If your input is `ISO-8859-1` as well, and your processing is fairly simple, then you could internally use this as a `byte[]` instead of `String` to remove this narrowing conversion entirely.